# Allocator named requirements -- exceptions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, allocator

[[allocator.requirements.general]/37](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#general-37)

> *Throws:* `allocate` may throw an appropriate exception.

Any limitations on "*appropriate*" implied elsewhere?

Can a valid custom allocator just throw a `double` on any request?

---

Context: implementation of a `noexcept` function that uses allocator, but has fallback strategy to do something if all allocations fail.

Comment: What's appropriate depends on the allocator and its use. If `double` makes sense for your allocator, go ahead.

Comment: from a users perspective a `double` isnt worse or bettern than some `foo::exception` that does not inherit from a standard exception. I suppose it is common sense that makes allocators not throw `double`s, but on the other hand it would be not nice if the standard would forbid it

Comment: I was able to find an old paper where the draft still required `allocate` to throw only `std::bad_alloc` or a derived type, but I wasn't able to find a paper discussing the removal of that part (which already is removed in C++98): https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N1008.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any limitations on "appropriate" implied elsewhere?

No. "Appropriate" qualifier has no objective meaning. It's effectively a suggestion to use common sense. There are no limitations on the type thrown from `allocate`.

> Can a valid custom allocator just throw a double on any request?

It would be conforming if the author considers double to be appropriate. I wouldn't consider it "appropriate" myself, but it's up to the author to decide.

> Context: implementation of a noexcept function that uses allocator, but has fallback strategy to do something if all allocations fail.

You should use a catch-all block:

```
try {
    ptr = a.allocate();
} catch(...) {
    // deal with it
}
```